# Apache mod_rewrite path name as query parameters?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to use Apache's `mod_rewrite` in order to be able to take each folder of a path as a particular query parameter, for example consider the following:

**Basic example**

Url requested: `http://domain.com/shoes/prada/image-1/`

Page served: `http://domain.com/?cid=shoes&bid=prada&pid=image-1`

In this scenario, there are 3 sub-folders requested (`/shoes/`, `/prada/` then `image-1`), so the first sub-folder is passed in the actual page served as `cid`, the second as `bid` and the third as `pid`.

**Full example**

However, I would also like it to serve a particular page depending on the number of sub-folders requested, e.g.

Url requested: `http://domain.com/shoes/prada/`

Page served: `http://domain.com/shop.php?cid=shoes&bid=prada`

So far all I've managed to find is regex based matching for `mod_rewrite` but my path's will vary a lot, which is why I would like to have conditions based on the number of folders accessed (please note, I'm not that good with regex - I reckon a wildcard character would help with this, but I wouldn't be sure where to start).

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated! This is pretty long winded, so if you need any more info for clarifying, please let me know!

Comment: @faa The 1st example was simply to show the basis of my question (e.g. parameters taken from folders), while the 2nd was to show a page being served based on the number of parameters. By "number of folders accessed" I meant the number of parameters passed with the idea that 1 folder = 1 parameter, like so /path/to/folder -> 1 = path, 2 = to, 3 = folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a little bit of work I was able to tweak some regex and get a working rule set for what I wanted:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.)?$ product.php?tid=$1&sid=$2&eid=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.)?$ brand.php?tid=$1&sid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.)?$ shop.php?tid=$1 [L]
```

This is a bit different to the example, however it's what I intended for in the first place.

This allows for the rewriting of url's up to four folders deep, with the "name" of each folder being given as a parameter, and each additional level of depth rewriting the url to a separate resource for example:

```
http://x.com/shoes/prada/2011-high-heels/ -> http://x.com/product.php?tid=shoes&sid=prada&eid=2011-high-heels
```

Tested on http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/