# Htaccess error in php page

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a question.

I have htacess file in my php page :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

And technically it works, for request like :

> page.com/news

, but i need to add 2 segments in url, similar to the example above

> page.com/type&style=something

How to get this to correct form, like :

> **page.com/type/something**

And does it change something in SEO, i mean, the page with /type/something will get higher stats in search engines than /type&name=something?

Thanks!

Comment: So you current rule is working and forwards to `/index.php?page=xxx`. But i don't understand something. Where should `/type/something` forward to ? You're talking about `/type&style=something` but what is it ? Existing rule ?

Comment: The /type&style=something need to be /something/ or /type/something/

Comment: Answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136521/apache-mod-rewrite-path-name-as-query-parameters).

Comment: Ok but where is forwarded `/type/something` ? To `index.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

For a solution with apache (see [Apache mod_rewrite path name as query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136521/apache-mod-rewrite-path-name-as-query-parameters)).

Another answer to the same question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658978/mod-rewrite-convert-folders-in-url-into-query-parameters). There it is suggested to do it with PHP and not with rewriting the URL.