# Rewrite URL with Query and directory in path

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL of the form: 
    http://www.example.com/ads/story.asp?story_id=73
that I would like to replace with: 
    https://www.example.com/news/awards-2015/

I have tried several methods from other stackoverflow posts, including the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/ads/story.asp$
RewriteCond   %{QUERY_STRING}   ^story_id=73$
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/news/awards-2015/   [R=301,L]
```

... without success.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong? Key differences from other examples appear to be 1) rewriting from an http URL to an https URL and 2) the additional directory "news" in the path of the URL to be rewritten.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136521/apache-mod-rewrite-path-name-as-query-parameters

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Zak. This example does show a URL with multiple folders, however, the URL I am trying to replace is the query URL. The suggested example is trying to replace a non-query URL with a query URL. Another difference (may or may not be important) is the URL I am trying to replace is 'http' while the one I am trying to serve is 'https'.

Comment: Zak - however the online tester mentioned in the post you gave me did identify that the "RewriteCond   %{REQUEST_URI}    ^/ads/story.asp$" is the problem. There must be some other way to test if this /folder/filename are in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)story_id=73(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule ads/story_detail.asp(.*)$ https://www.example.com/news/awards-2015/? [R=301,L]
```